# Can not start MongoDB in other folder path and getting some warning

Tags: mongodb

I have one issue while running MongoDB. I created one folder and need to run the MongoDB there.When i typed commend `mongod --dbpath pathname` and pressed enter key it gave me the following messages and terminated.

```
2016-01-12T09:41:46.359+0530 I CONTROL
2016-01-12T09:41:46.359+0530 W CONTROL  32-bit servers don't have journaling ena
bled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
2016-01-12T09:41:46.359+0530 I CONTROL
Invalid command: and
```

I am using `win-xp` and need to run mongoDB in different path.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Journaling is disabled by default in 32 bit systems. If you want to enable it use - - journal parameter along with mongod --dbpath pathname.  There are several restrictions with 32 bit systems. Your database size would be limited to 2gb and if you enable journal feature it would again reduce the database size.. You can reduce the impact of Journaling by using - - smallfiles parameter..

Comment: For db path you can use data/db directory.. Or any directory of your choice.. You can disable journal using - - nojournal parameter

Comment: Then what is the command for this.

Comment: mongod --port 27017 --dbpath <pathname> --journal it starts with journal enabled..  mongod --port 27017 --dbpath <pathname> --nojournal starts with journal disabled.. Always good to have journal enabled for durability. For 32 bit systems you have to take  a call based on database size..

Comment: Can you paste the complete error?? Is there any directory path like data/db?? Sometimes it could be because of mongod.lock file..

Comment: I have tested by using your command the warning message gone but still one issue coming `Invalid command: and` and then options coming.

Comment: Can you paste the complete error or screenshot please??? Your win-xp is 32 bit or 64 bit???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100434/discussion-between-satya-and-harshavmb).

Comment: We can raise a jira with mongodb but I suspect they are not supporting xp at the moment.. As its life cycle is complete

This is a bug..

You can check by opening mongod.bat file

Comment: Ok..but thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

For 32 build systems, there are some constraints. Database size shouldn't go beyond 2GB. If you turn on journaling, your database file shrink further.

So, to start mongod with journaling in the directory path you are interested.

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath <db-path> --journal
```

To start mongod without journaling

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath <db-path> --nojournal
```

or

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath <db-path>
```

because for 32 bit systems journaling is disabled by default.

You can use `--smallfiles` with journaling which works really good for journal files,